# Reference my project code from imported pod code

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm using a pod called `SimpleImageViewer` and I found a way to implement a button in the pod file. But how can I trigger a function from the pod file in my own project?

I think this is because of the different project scopes, but I don't know how I can build a reference.

Here is the code I wrote into the pod file, but I get an error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'PhotoEventVC'

```
@IBAction func closeButtonPressed() {
    PhotoEventVC.shared.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done the following way. Make your `SimpleImageViewer` have property

```
var onCloseButtonPressed : (()->())?
```

then the `closeButtonPressed` function looks like this:

```
@IBAction func closeButtonPressed() {
    onCloseButtonPressed?()
}
```

then you just need to set the property from within your project like this:

```
simpleImageViewer.onCloseButtonPressed = { PhotoEventVC.shared.close() }
```

where `simpleImageViewer` is an instance of `SimpleImageViewer`

As far as referencing a project from a pod is concerned it is an extremely bad idea because this way the pod can be used only with one project and therefore should not be a pod at all, it should be a part of the project